# Android-Studio: Java logs missing when debugging JNI

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, java-native-interface

I am facing a issue in AndroidStudio after i updated AndroidStudio to 2.2.1 and also updated my project to use the latest gradle (2.14.1) and gradle-plugin (2.2.1), and implemented some cpp/jni code (CMakeList setup).

Before i did this changes, when i started debugging my app, AndroidStudio would open a "debug" panel with a Console that displayed logs from java.

Now after the update and cpp integration, this debug-panel still opens, but now i have 2 tabs in there, each containing a Console (1 for cpp and 1 for java output). But the java console stopped displaying any of my java logs.
all that gets printed to this console is:
 `Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'`

In the cpp console i get a few lines of output. This contains the logs from the apk install process ($adb push ...   $adb shell pm install ...  $adb shell am start ...), and than some logs that tell me that it waited for the app to come online, than started a LLDB server and finally attached the Debugger to the process.

I can set breakpoints both in java and in cpp, just the the java logs stopped working.

I have the feeling that i am missing something obvious.

Hope someone has seen this problem before and can tell me how i get my java logs back to show up in one of the Consoles.

[Update:]
When i just run the apk, not debugging, the console of the "run" panel displays logs from both cpp and java. Only when debugging, i get no logs. neither from cpp nor from java.

Answer (score 0):

ok. When debugging i can see my java and cpp logs inside the "logcat"-console ("Android Monitor"-tab). I did set the filter to "Verbose" and "Show only selected application". 
Of course the application also needs to be selected (Dropdown at top of "Android Monitor"-panel).

I think this is more a workaround than a answer to my question. 
It would be better if i could see the logs in the debug-panels so they are separated between cpp and java).

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum. If you want to add information don't misuse an answer - edit quer question instead!

Comment: You might be right. On the other hand the answer i posted could be the answer to my issue. e.g. it might be possible that using the logcat console is the only option for logs when debugging JNI. Well, i cant be sure, so it was probably wrong to put it as answer. Anyway thank you for pointing it out and not just leaving a downvote without a message...